# Android App Consumes Memory

Tags: android, image, memory-management, memory-leaks

[image]

After alot of scrolling the memory goes up to:
[image]

I have simple android app that shows list if images but the memory appears to be high i'm using Picasso for loading images into the list and here is my code for loading images:

```
@BindingAdapter({"thumbnail_cars"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, Cars cars) {
        Log.e("width ",String.valueOf((Converter.getScreenWidth()-40)*0.4));
        Log.e("height ",String.valueOf(Converter.convertDpToPixel(130)));
        float margins = Converter.convertDpToPixel(20);

        String widthUrl = cars.getImage().replace("[w]",String.valueOf((Converter.getScreenWidth()-margins)*0.4));
        String heightUrl = widthUrl.replace("[h]",String.valueOf(Converter.convertDpToPixel(130)));
        imageDownloader.loadImage(heightUrl, imageView,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: why you think that `the memory appears to be high`?

Comment: I guess the normal usage is around 27 MB

Comment: there is no *normal usage* value for the app in general. Each app has it's own *normal usage*

Comment: It is just normal list with images and look how it goes up to 64 MB after scrolling i don't know if that normal

Comment: images are memory-consuming itself. The memory will be GCed once it is required, unless you have implemented images loading incorrectly.

Comment: Just using this method to load images in the adapter
:  
public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView, int placeholderID) {
        picasso.load(url).placeholder(placeholderID).into(imageView);
    }

Comment: it should be fine than